# Исключить повторное нажатие на кнопку (Android)

Tags: android

Нужно исключить повторное нажатие на кнопку, тоесть один раз нажал и кнопка стала после этого ненажимабельной =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void disableClick(View v) {
   btn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: @Gorets, может все-таки `setEnabled(false)`?